# No se puede crear el archivo de registro

Tags: linux, web, kali-linux

nos se por que al usar el programa de httrack y querer clonar una pagina web me salta un error el cual me dicta lo siguiente :

> (kali㉿kali)-[~/Desktop/web]
> httrack https://ejemplo.es/ejemplo/index.php -O /Desktop/web
>
> - Unable to create log file /Desktop/web/hts-log.txt

Alquien sabe como se soluciona ??

Comment: La ruta `/Desktop/web` existe? Ahí estás poniendo una ruta absoluta y estás diciendo que hay una carpeta a nivel de la raíz (junto a etc, opt, usr, home) llamada Desktop con una subcarpeta web...

Comment: un `sudo` delante podría funcionar si el tema es de permisos de carpeta :)

Answer (score 1):

La ruta /Desktop (raíz del SO, carpeta Desktop) probablemente no exista, quizás lo quieras hacer en la home de tu usuario

Intenta con

```
httrack https://ejemplo.es/ejemplo/index.php -O ~/Desktop/web

httrack https://ejemplo.es/ejemplo/index.php -O /home/<nombreusuario>/Desktop/web
```